# beginner android studio programmer

Tags: java, android, import

I am a new programmer for android studio.

For my class I am importing 
`android.content.ContentResolver`
&
`android.content.ContentProvider`

Both packages have `applyBatch` & `bulkInsert` methods, but when I start typing within the class (cool shortcut within android studio) bu.. or ap.. the `bulkInsert` & the `applyBatch` from the `ContentProvider` package appear, but not from the `ContentResolver` package.

The ...`ContentResolver` import is not as bright as the `ContentProvider`, because it is an "unused import statement."

My question is how to make `ContentResolver`'s methods available or what additional tasks do I have to do make it accessable.

I right-clicked ..`ContentResolver` and selected "Go To" > "Declaration".  It did find that class and it did have the declarations of `applyBatch` & `bulkInsert` within `ContentResolver`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you should try some Java coding without an IDE to get to know and understand the basic language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = new ContentResolver();
contentResolver.applyBatch();
contentResolver.bulkInsert();

ContentProvider contentProvider = new ContentProvider();
contentProvider.applyBatch();
contentProvider.bulkInsert();
```

IF are static, than:

```
ContentResolver.applyBatch();
ContentProvider.applyBatch();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You just reminded me of something that I originally did. I declared the class like: public final class name extends ContentProvider { I mistakenly forgot that is how I declared the class. thanks again.

I would give you points, but I do not have 15 points so I am unable to give points.